# SecuGen Hamster Plus device not working with Java applet in Chrome and Firefox browsers in .NET web form with Telerik controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, telerik, applet

I am facing an issue with the SecuGen Hamster Plus device not working with a Java applet in Chrome and Firefox browsers in a .NET web form with Telerik controls. I have followed the guidelines provided by SecuGen, but the device is not detected by the Java applet in these browsers.. The applet works fine in Internet Explorer, but I need to make it work in Chrome and Firefox as well.

I am using a .NET web form with Telerik controls for my application. Are there any additional steps or workarounds that I can try to fix this issue? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I understand that Java applets are deprecated and not recommended due to security concerns, but for this particular scenario, I need to use the SecuGen Hamster Plus device with a Java applet in Chrome and Firefox browsers.

Comment: Change the UserAgent : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent?force_isolation=true